# How to set minimum date on Bootstrap datepicker in Asp.net core?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

This is native bootstrap datepicker input form.

**I want to set a minimum date below which the user cant click on**, but my solution is not working.

**Whats the right way to make this work?**

My code:

```
  <input class="form-control" type="date"  min="@DateTime.Today.Date" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me:**

<input class="form-control" type="date"  min="@DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />

All dates before today are greyed out.